# Confuse about Yii2 session

Tags: php, yii, yii2

I use Yii2 framework to do my PHP project. But I ran into some trouble. Here is my code.
First, set session variable through yii2 session api like this:

```
Yii::$app->session->set('test', 123);
```

Then in other action, I hope to get this variable:

```
var_dump(Yii::$app->session);

@session_start();
var_dump($_SESSION);

var_dump(Yii::$app->session['test']);
```

But I found the the result:

```
object(yii\web\Session)#109 (6) {
  ["flashParam"]=>
  string(7) "__flash"
  ["handler"]=>
  NULL
  ["_cookieParams":"yii\web\Session":private]=>
  array(1) {
    ["httponly"]=>
    bool(true)
  }
  ["_hasSessionId":"yii\web\Session":private]=>
  NULL
  ["_events":"yii\base\Component":private]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["_behaviors":"yii\base\Component":private]=>
  NULL
}
array(2) {
  ["__flash"]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["test"]=>
  int(123)
}
int(123)
```

I wondered why Yii::$app->session CAN NOT dump the value of the key 'test' at the first var_dump.

Comment: refer : http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/yii2/3584/session/12367/session-in-yii2#t=201610181227147314455

Answer (score 0):

For retrieve a session entry Try using  `session->get()`

```
 $app->session->get('test') ;
```

eg:

```
var_dump( $app->session->get('test')  );
```

take a look at this guide for some sample  and suggestion  http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-runtime-sessions-cookies.html

Comment: thanks for ur answer but my point is not how to get the 'test' value. It's that I don't understand WHY. Because $app->session is an OBJECT, then why the array usage $app->session['test'] work? How can it get a key value like this from an object. That confused me.

Comment: If  you  look at the object  is an object of 6 element the 6th is an array and contain as second  entry an entry named 'test'  so you can access  test as an array because in an array inside an object  eg: Yii::$app->session['test']) ... hope this comment is useful ..

Comment: The 6th element is ["_behaviors":"yii\base\Component":private]=>NULL. While I try to var_dump $_SESSION, it contained 'test' value which you saw